# log4net how to change logging level of appender from code of certain appender

Tags: c#, log4net

I have log4net.config with multiple appender
Form C# code i wanted to override minLvel of logging of certain appender

My appender setting is like

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <file value="..\\Logs\\Api" />
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
            <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}&#9;%p&#9;%t&#9;%property{Ip}&#9;%property{Context}&#9;%property{ContextId}&#9;%c{1}&#9;%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Any one have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my Current solution.

```
private static void SetFilterMinLogLevel(AppenderSkeleton appender, string inputLevel)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputLevel))
            {
                inputLevel = inputLevel.ToLower().Trim();
                IFilter filterHead = appender.FilterHead;
                LevelRangeFilter filterLevel = filterHead as LevelRangeFilter;
```

if (filterLevel == null)// one of my appender have one custom filter as well
{
filterHead = appender.FilterHead.Next;
filterLevel = filterHead as LevelRangeFilter; ;

```
            }
                if (filterLevel != null)
                {
                    switch (inputLevel)
                    {
                        case "info":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Info;//todo
                            break;
                        case "debug":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Debug;//todo
                            break;
                        case "warn":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Warn;//todo
                            break;
                        case "error":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Error;//todo
                            break;
                        case "fatal":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Fatal;//todo
                            break;
                        case "off":
                            filterLevel.LevelMin = filterLevel.LevelMax = log4net.Core.Level.Off;//trying to check switching off logs
                            break;
                        default:
                            Logger.DebugFormat("Unknown Log level {0}",inputLevel);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: minor enhancement as one appender have one more custom filter on which this was not working. also checking if i can swtich off logging as well if possible